# Linux distributions centered on Plasma desktop?

Tags: linux, kde, desktop-environment, distributions, plasma5

I am looking for a good respectable Linux - I mean stable not necessarily because based on stable releases like Ubuntu LTS, but because well supported by maintainers and community - that would be focused on Plasma/KDE desktop as their main DE in the way Ubuntu is on Gnome (and especially was on Unity), Mint (especially) on Cinnamon, Solus on Budgie, Elementary on Pantheon, Bodhi on Enlightenment etc.

Plasma was always for me the most complex, interesting and intelligent desktop - but is there a main distribution focused on it and committed to its promotion?

---

*In case this question may seem off-topic here - and maybe more suited on Software Recommendations stackexchange, please do not down-vote or close, but flag it to be moved or move it if you can.*

Comment: I would like to delete this, as I have posted a [softwarerecs.stackexchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/80707/22326) one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org/download) is a distribution directly made by KDE for KDE. I bet you cannot go much more bleeding-edge KDE than this. Apart from it being based on Ubuntu LTS, I cannot state much about it as I never used it.

**Note**: the official KDE statement on Neon is, that it is rather the fastest repository for KDE and that KDE of course will not drop availability for as many distros as possible. So have a careful read of their [FAQs](https://neon.kde.org/faq).

Furthermore Kubuntu of course is the Canonical's official KDE-focused variant of Ubuntu.

And Debian offers Plasma as **one** of its standard DEs - Debian does not really differentiate regarding preferred DEs, but you can bet that the version the offer is comparably stable, yet a bit older, and runs smoothly on a Debian system.

Comment: After reading closely their FAQ and especially after installing Neon I cannot longer accept it as the answer, which probably leaves Kubuntu as the one.

Comment: I would like to delete this, as I have posted a separate one, more properly defined, on ["Software Recommendations"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/80707/22326). Please delete your answer so I can delete my question and be welcome to answer under the new one. Thanks.